# How to apply a ranking algorithm using PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, ranking

I'm working on an algorithm that gives a score to some messages posted on a website. This score will be used to rank all the messages. If, for one message, the score is high, this message will be ranked above the other messages (that have a lower score) and vice versa. The parameters for this algorithm are the number of upvotes/downvotes and the number of seconds gone by since the message was posted.

I want to display the millions of messages on a webpage using PHP and MySQL. Of course I will use a paging system. Since one of the parameters for the algorithm is the number of seconds gone by since the message was posted, this score will change over the time. But I will need to update it. The only way for me to update the score of each message is to update it automatically with PHP when the client asks for the messages to be displayed, then call them with a MySQL request like that : `SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY score`.

But because there are millions of messages, it would take a lot of time to update everything each time someone wants to see some messages.

How do I implement this in PHP ?

So basically, I'm asking how to rank messages (using a score) without having to calculate the score of each message before I call them (because it would take a lot of time) + because I'm gonna be using a paging system, only 20 or 30 messages will be selected at a time from the database.

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does the score of a message still change after a long enough period of time without any new upvote/downvote? Would it be possible to flag such messages as 'sleeping ones' on which there's no need to compute a score update?

Comment: Your question may be clear to you, but it is not to us. You can create events to run (I have three links off my profile for that). You set the schedule for the event(s) such as calculating a score for the ones where score is null, or an updt DT is null, or there is some activity related to it. But none of that is defined well in your question. Just this nebulous notion of ranking things.

Comment: @Arnauld : I didn't think about that. The messages will just get a very low score if they are, let's say 2 years old, compared to messages that were just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a field which holds miliseconds since 1970 when a post is created. then use the following:

```
select milisecondsSince1970 as t,votes as v,* from messages order by (v-a*(t-t0))
```

where:

- "a" is your personal factor for giving desired weight to "t".
- t0 is miliseocnds from an exact date which you consider it as
  start date rather than 1970.

This solution just works for you question as the criterion of score is "time". In other huge calculations , a periodic update on scores is suggestd.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know you could do something like that with a simple MySQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Updating in real time will be difficult, and expensive in terms of performance. But I have suggestion - you can use a MySQL events scheduler to schedule JOB at regular intervals may be every half hour depending upon DB size. Running batch script as cron job on regular intervals may also work but direct Event execution in MySQL is better choice. 
Since rank is calculated based on age of post and votes, so a stored procedure will work.

Other solution, I recommend - run update query to calculate rank on result set as data in shown in paginated form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is a good idea, but I have the hope that one day my site gets popular so that a lot of messages are sent every day. If it does get popular, it would ask to much performances to update all my database daily.

Comment: Yes, then you can use database clustering and with combination of NoSQL Database storing the ranks. NoSQL database performs well with data that does not change frequently.
P.S vote if you like